# jquery added content not working

Tags: jquery

On a test webpage where I'm teaching myself javascript and the jquery & soon ajax libraries. I've got the table which is shown down below with an edit image button. When that image is clicked the text to its left is successfully taken and copied to an input box which is put in its place. However, the save image button which is put in place of the edit image button doesn't work, not even a simple alert. This can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/DVcFU/2/

I'm a beginner with javascript as you might guess, so I'm not exactly sure where I've gone wrong or what to do next. I'm guessing I have to do some sort of initialization of the element. Any help is appreciated.

I'm using jquery-1.10.2

```
<script src="../java/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

**Javascrip Edit Function**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //edit entry script
    $(".edit_entry").click(function(){
            //gets the text from the textbox
            var text  = $(this).parent().prev().text();

            //replaces the textbox and edit button with an input box and save button
            var html_code1 = "<input id='editing' type='text' value='" + text + "'>";
            var html_code2 = "<td><img src='/img/saveicon.png' class='save_entry' style='display:inline; cursor:pointer' border='0' alt='Save Entry'></td>";
            $(this).parent().prev().replaceWith(html_code1);
            $(this).parent().html(html_code2);
    });
});
</script>
```

**Javascript Save Function**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //save entry script
    $(".save_entry").click(function(){
    alert("Hello World");
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href='www.google.com'>Generic link</a></td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Time</td>
        <td>Details</td>
        <td><img src="/img/editicon.png" class="edit_entry" style="display:inline; cursor:pointer" border="0" alt="Edit Entry"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why is your javascript in a folder named `java`...

Comment: Do you have suggestion of where else to put javascript files which will possibly be used by multiple pages? Or are you inferring that there should be just a copy of every javascript file used in each folder.

Comment: No, it's just that, java has nothing to do with javascript. they are two very different programming languages. Not that it's very important, it just could be confusing for a moment to someone else looking at the folder structure.

Comment: Honestly, I wasn't even thinking about java when I made the folder, thanks for pointing that out though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(".save_entry").click()` only binds the event to elements that exist at the point when that line is ran.  You need to use a "delegated" event for elements added later on.

```
$(document).on('click', '.save_entry', function(){
    alert("Hello World");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use event delegation

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //save entry script
    $(document).on('click', ".save_entry", function(){
    alert("Hello World");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using generated content use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/), which will bind the events to current and newly generated content

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //edit entry script
    $(document).on("click",".edit_entry",function(){
            //gets the text from the textbox
            var text  = $(this).parent().prev().text();

            //replaces the textbox and edit button with an input box and save button
            var html_code1 = "<input id='editing' type='text' value='" + text + "'>";
            var html_code2 = "<td><img src='/img/saveicon.png' class='save_entry' style='display:inline; cursor:pointer' border='0' alt='Save Entry'></td>";
            $(this).parent().prev().replaceWith(html_code1);
            $(this).parent().html(html_code2);
    });

    $(document).on("click",".save_entry",function(){
            alert("Hello World");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If You want to add an event in a dynamic way in jQuery, then in my experience the simplest thing is to use the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

Compared to Your example the method has only some very simple differences.

Your code should look like this in order to reach Your goal:

```
$(document).on("click", ".save_entry", function () {
   alert("Hello World");
});
```

instead of:

```
$(".save_entry").click(function () {
   alert("Hello World");
});
```